# Does Planet revolution time is always greater the more it's getting away from the center?

Tags: planets, orbital-motion

The entire question is in the title .

It's the case for the solar system but is it always the case ? Can a planet do a revolution faster than another that is closer to the center ?

As far as I searched , it's not but I prefer ask here to be sure.

Of course I'm talking about similar orbits (all with the same eccentricity).
(When I'm talking of the center, I mean the body in the center (in general a sun), even if it's not always the center)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a year period, right? There is [Kepler's Third Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law):

$$ {S_1^3 \over S_2^3} = {P_1^2 \over P_2^2} .$$
where

- S - is the distances between the 'center' and a planet
- P - orbital period of the planet

Thus **the further the planet is from the center (Sun), the longer its orbital period is**. You can check that formula by taking examples of Earth (`150million kilometers` and `365days`) and Mercury (`58million kilometers`, and `you can calculate the length of its year`).

Answer (score 2):

Kepler's Third Law says that the square of a planet's orbital period is proportional to the cube of its semi-major axis;
$$
  T^2 \propto a^3
$$
So if one planet has a larger semi-major axis than another, then its orbital period will necessarily be longer.  Assuming that we define "closeness to the center" of a planet by the size of the semi-major axis of its orbit, the answer to your question is no.